# Disable SUBMIT button until select box choices

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small form.

Two select box elements and a submit button.

The select box elements collectively when selections are chosen, fire off an ajax request.

What I want to do is, disable the submit button UNTIL user has made selections from the select drop downs.

They must make a selection from BOTH select drop downs, before the Submit button is enabled.

I dont mind if the submit button is hidden until selections made.

Brief Code:

```
<form id="ad_form" method="post" action="">
    <p>
        <select id="ad_type" name="ad_type">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Select premium ad type</option>
            <option value="<?php echo TYPE_USER;?>">Featured Agent</option>
            <option value="<?php echo TYPE_LISTING;?>">Featured Listing</option>
        </select>
        <label for="ad_type" class="labelStrong">Advertising Type</label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <select id="ad_duration" name="ad_duration">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Select premium ad duration</option>
            <option value="weekly">Weekly</option>
            <option value="fortnightly">Fortnightly</option>
            <option value="monthly">Monthy</option>
        </select>
        <label for="ad_duration" class="labelStrong">Advertising Duration</label>
    </p>

    <p>
        <div id="calender">
        </div>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submitorder" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: you can listen for the select button on change events and then check to see if the selections have been made.

Comment: You should try jQuery form validation:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation

Comment: change the type of your submit to "button" and when the select's fire then change it to "submit" a "button" doesn't submit the form

Comment: Can anyone knock up a scribble ?

Comment: just a thought on this subject: remember that you still need to validate server-side too, as javascript disabled would be the first way to try to hack your validation if its protecting interesting data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a demo that seems to do what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/Yr59d/

That javascript code would go in a `$(document).ready()` block

Comment: So every time a new required dropdown is added you have to update the validation routine?  Thanks, but no thanks.

Comment: Thankyou, @cycherry works great.
I am crap with JS etc so have no idea what you mean @Kon

Answer (score 2):

If you give all your selects a common class name (like 'required') , you can do something like this:

```
$('select.required').change(function() {
  var total = $('select.required').length;
  var selected = $('select.required option:selected').length;

  $('#submitorder').attr('disabled', (selected == total));
});
```

This is not tested code.  [This documentation](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) might help.  [This jquery discussion](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/disable-submit-button-on-form-submit-solved) might help too.

Comment: My Submit button is: <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submitorder" /> , so how do we disable based on your code, do I simply change name="submit" to something else?

Comment: Well... the "$('#submitorder').attr('disabled'..." part does the disabling and enabling.

Comment: I cannot get your code to work, but the other code snippets I can ( from other members ) not sure why.

Comment: This is merely a guide - not tested code.  But if you were looking for a total handout, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
    $("#submitorder").css("visibility", "hidden");

    $("#ad_form select").bind("change", function() { 
        if ($("#ad_type").val().length > 0 && $("#ad_duration").val().length > 0) {
           $("#submitorder").css("visibility", "visible");
        } else {
           $("#submitorder").css("visibility", "hidden");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Same as ctcherry's answer - hard-coded for the two selects.  Yuck.

Comment: Thanks Adam , will check it out

Comment: True, but there is no need to over architect such a straight forward requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Gah, I'll have to agree with Kon on this one - fix-now-worry-about-it-later answers have their place but an *elegant* solution that is simple at the same time has to be the way to go.

My solution: (with credit from a thread at: [JQuery Enable / Disable Submit Button in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236727/jquery-enable-disable-submit-button-in-ie7))

```
$('select.required').change(function() {
  var total =  = $('select.required').length;
  var selected = $('#ad_form').find("select.required option[value!='':selected").length;

  $('#submitorder').prop('disabled', (selected != total));
});
```

Incidentally, thanks ctcherry for demoing the code on the JSFiddle site - I've not seen that before and will make use of it in the future!

Answer (score -1):

Use listeners on both select buttons for change and check whether the other is also set. If set, enable the submit button.