# Validation in drop downs on submit button click using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have three drop-down fields. I want to validate them using JavaScript when the submit button is clicked to see if any of the values in the three drop-down fields are not selected.

On click of submit button it should display a warning message indicating that one of the three drop-downs have not been filled.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. What have you tried/Where are you running into problems?

Comment: As I am new to javascript.I want to do the validation on the three dropdownlist.I am unable to do the validation.If any of the data is not selected in any of the dropdown then on click of submit button it should display an alert message with specific to the dropdown list name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable SUBMIT button until select box choices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559983/disable-submit-button-until-select-box-choices)

Comment: can you add some sample of your code to help you out here? Maybe set it up in JSFiddle so we can see what you have already been trying.

Comment: right now i do not have the sample of code..I have to implement it from scratch..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information in the comments from my previous answer, this should work for you. I have tested it but you can refine the JavaScript `if` statement to test each individually and report a different message for each as long as you you always `return false;` to make sure the submission gets halted

```js
function validateForm() {
  if (document.getElementById("ddOne").value == "" || document.getElementById("ddTwo").value == "" || document.getElementById("ddThree").value == "") {
    alert("You need to fill in all three dropboxes and not just some");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
    <label>Dropdown 1</label>
    <select id="ddOne">
      <option value="">None</option>
      <option value="Opt1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="Opt2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="Opt3">Option 3</option>
      <option value="Opt4">Option 4</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <label>Dropdown 2</label>
    <select id="ddTwo">
      <option value="">None</option>
      <option value="Opt1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="Opt2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="Opt3">Option 3</option>
      <option value="Opt4">Option 4</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <label>Dropdown 3</label>
    <select id="ddThree">
      <option value="">None</option>
      <option value="Opt1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="Opt2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="Opt3">Option 3</option>
      <option value="Opt4">Option 4</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using JavaScript, have you tried taking advantage of the `required` attribute of the `select` HTML tag?

When used, a drop-down field should look somewhat like this:

```
<select required>
   <option value="">None</option>
   <option value="Opt1">Option 1</option>
   <option value="Opt2">Option 2</option>
   <option value="Opt3">Option 3</option>
   <option value="Opt4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

When setup this way, you cannot submit a button for the form body without having a value defined option selected for that field.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but as i already said..I marked the field as "required" but I m facing issue to implement the required functionality.Can anyone provide the complete code to validate each dropdown.Or if any of the value is not selected in three of the dropdown then  on "submit" button click it should perform the validation on all the three dropdowns.

Comment: In my tests when I use the `required` designation on a select list, it will bring me to the unfilled drop-down and tell me I need to select an option. It does this when I hit submit. 

I am sorry but at the time I responded I did not see any indication that you had tried the `required` attribute on the fields.

I will take a look and see what I might have for the task you require, but I have not had much need to do something this way when the solution does not need JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks Kenneth for the prompt response..Your help will be highly appreciated...I need to submit this assignment by today..

Comment: Ah, an assignment for class. Yea those can be quite the nuisance since you cannot just do it the easy way.

Comment: Please add the sample code provided in the prompt then so we can accurately prepare your response the way it was expected to be given

Comment: right now i do not have the sample of code..I have to implement it from scratch..

Comment: @AnonymusPT I have added a new Answer that should give you exactly what you were looking for